# PHP website not running on cpanel shared hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

I don't have a .htaccess file. I created .htaccess in my /public_html folder and tried various codes for it from google but none works. 
HTML pages are working fine. But no php files are executing, even a basic PHP code having echo code.

Comment: are you sure PHP is installed and available?

Comment: Yes! The customer support guy said I need a .htaccess file. But I don't know what should be the code in it.

Comment: Can you share with us what you've already attempted

Comment: Order deny,allow
Allow from all

<Files "*.php">
    Allow from all
</Files>

Comment: I do not think this is the correct approach. Your server (Apache/Nginx or else) should be configured to serve php content directly not from a .htaccess which has other configuration purposes.

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: "What should I do then?" - Change the hosting provider..

Comment: Done it a week ago! :/

Comment: Please place a link and code example.